# How to deal with lange amount of views in android?

Tags: android, view

I'll try to be brief:
In my android application I have a large amount of views (30 - 40) to display on a single screen, children to a ScrollView object.
Now, said views are nothing but buttons and textviews representing single products details and when pressed, a simple method is called and all I need to pass is a value (int) representing the product.
I was wondering how to avoid the hassle of having to type in the code for each view witch would result into dozens of lines of pain:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1 :
          simpleMethod(1);
          break;
        case R.id.btn2 :
          simpleMethod(2);
          break;
        case R.id.btn3 :
          simpleMethod(3);
          break;
      }
    }
```

..and so forth for all of the views.
Consider that there's more than a simpleMethod() to call whenever a button is pressed.

My guess was to use a Map in witch the key would be the view id aka R.id.something and the value would simply be a number to pass to the method.

What are other efficient ways of handling large amount of views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can give tags to your views and then:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    simpleMethod(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag()));
}
```